# Set button title programmatically

Tags: ios, uibutton

I made a button in storyboard and associated it with an IBAction in my header file. How can I set the title of this button to the variable I made `displayPhone` and have it call that number as well?

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface IBThirdViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) PFRelation *agentRelation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *agent;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *agentName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *agentPhone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *agentEmail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *agentImage;

- (IBAction)phoneButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "IBThirdViewController.h"
#import "IBAgentsTableViewController.h"

@interface IBThirdViewController ()    

@end

@implementation IBThirdViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {        
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //Find the Agent and show it
    self.agentRelation = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"agentRelation"];
    PFQuery *query = [self.agentRelation query];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // success

            self.agent = objects;
            // Do something with the found objects
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"name: %@", [object objectForKey:@"name"]);
                NSLog(@"email: %@", [object objectForKey:@"email"]);

                NSString *displayEmail = [object objectForKey:@"email"];
                NSString *displayName = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSString *displayPhone = [object objectForKey:@"phone"];

                PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"profilePic"];
                NSURL *imageFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:thumbnail.url];
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileURL];


                self.agentEmail.text = displayEmail;
                self.agentName.text = displayName;
                self.agentPhone.text = displayPhone;
                self.agentImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];                        
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];        
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showEditAgent"]) {
        IBAgentsTableViewController *viewController = (IBAgentsTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        viewController.agents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.agent];
    }
}

- (IBAction)phoneButton:(id)sender {

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need connect button from xib with `IBOutlet` object:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *displayPhone;
```

Then set it's title in `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` after loading data:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //...
    // Load data here
    //...
    [self.displayPhone setTitle:displayPhone forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Finally implement `IBAction` method for button:

```
- (IBAction)phoneButton:(id)sender {
    NSString *phone = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Remove all chars except of digits
    static NSString *const kDigitsString = @"0123456789";
    phone = [[phone componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:kDigitsString] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    // Initiate call
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phone]]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to iOS and forgot I had to add an outlet as well. The only issue now is when I press the number (555) 555-5555 nothing happens.

Comment: @Packy I have updated my answer with code for removing all non-digit chars. Now iOS should start call when you tap the button.

Comment: Thanks. I just was finishing up my code to do that, just came to me that might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't connected the button to an outlet but only to an action.

First you need to connect it to an outlet (like you've done with the labels).

Then use...

```
[self.button setTitle:@"blah" forState:UIViewControlStateNormal];
```

Something like that anyway. I'm currently on my iPhone so I don't have auto complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the title inside the IBAction method do:

```
[sender setTitle:@"My title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If you want to change in any other place you need a @property of uibutton, something like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *phoneButtonProperty;
```

and connect it to your button and then

[phoneButtonProperty setTitle:@"My title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];